# Stuck with ASPNETCOMPILER : error ASPRUNTIME: Type is not resolved for member 'FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfigurationException,FluentNHibernate

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm using Team City for continual integration, for a .Net 4 ASP MVC 3 application.

On my dev machine I can build and run my application, but on the build sever I'm getting the following error:

```
 ASPNETCOMPILER : error ASPRUNTIME: Type is not resolved for member 'FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfigurationException,FluentNHibernate, Version=1.2.0.712, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8aa435e3cb308880'
```

The FluentNHibernate assembly is referenced by the project and I've even added the assembly to the web.config assemblies section, but I still get the error.

What can I do to diagnose the problem?

Comment: Can you check whether the FluentNHibernate dll is in the bin folder of your application?

Comment: Yep ,the assembly is in the bin folder and the version numbers match.

Comment: Ok, then please check the bin folder on your local server and that on your dev machine to see whether they are exactly same.

Comment: Yep, The files are binary identical. I've had some more time to hack about with things this weekend and it looks like it's something to do with my Ioc in a WebActivator.PreApplicationStartMethod call, taking the same call and simply moving it into the Application_Start seems to fix things up.

Answer (score 10):

To sum up Rob White's comment, the problem is certain code running in `WebActivator.PreApplicationStartMethod`. The fix is to move that code into `Application_Start` in the `Global.asax`.

The `WebActivator.PreApplicationStartMethod` is an assembly attribute for loading code extremely early in the build process. [Phil Haack](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/05/16/three-hidden-extensibility-gems-in-asp-net-4.aspx) give a good description. The attribute is supposed to be used for registering build providers and other things that are used later in the build process. As such, the ASPNET compiler has to load and run this code in order to begin compilation of views.

I got this particular error on appharbor after I added some code to my IoC (StructureMap) startup code that accessed a resource (MongoDB). Since this resource wasn't accessible to the appharbor build machine, it threw all kinds of errors.

The takeaway is that `PreApplicationStartMethod` is meant for **pre-application-start** things, like **building**, not initializing the application. If you're doing app initialization things, do it in `Global.asax` `Application_Start`. I know the default StructureMap NuGet package for MVC4 uses the attribute instead of `Global`. There might be other packages that lead you to that same mistake.

Comment: Thank you so much, I've been pulling my hair out over this issue.

Comment: This resolved the error but caused a ton of problems with SimpleInjector